# Ggvis bar chart - Choosing colors

Tags: r, visualization, ggvis, kaggle

I'm using the Kaggle '[train](http://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/course/Kaggle/train.csv)' data set.

It contains 891 rows. The column I'm using is ~Survived. This column consists of factor values '0' and '1'.

I have plotted the two values using the following lines of code:

```
train %>% ggvis(~Survived, fill = ~Survived) %>%
  layer_bars()
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

I would like to give the bar for values '0' a red color and the bar for the values '1' a green color.

Could someone help me out?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide a link for the used dataset? thanks.

Comment: Hi, I added the link under the word 'train'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `?scale_nominal`.  Scaling is different than with `ggplot2` - there are only three [scales](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/0.1/properties-scales.html#scale-arguments).

```
library(ggvis)

set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(Survived = factor(sample(0:1, 50, rep=T)))

dat %>% ggvis(~Survived, fill=~Survived) %>%
  layer_bars() %>%
  scale_nominal("fill", range = c("red", "green"))
```

Answer (score 1):

using mutate from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

train %>% mutate(mycolours = ifelse(Survived == 0, "red", "green")) %>%
    ggvis(~Survived, fill := ~mycolours) %>%
    layer_bars()
```

Comment: Adding this into shinyapps throws the following error:

    Attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'